# Blobstore Images Disappearing on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Google announce that the file API (blobstore) is deprecated earlier this year - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api

so we port our app to Google Cloud Storage - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/files_api_migration

But we didn't move the existing files stored in Blobstore

> What do I do with my existing files stored in Blobstore?
>
> You might want to consider moving these files to Cloud Storage. If you
>   do not wish to move them all to Cloud Storage, you can continue to
>   read and serve these legacy files using the Blobstore API, and use
>   Cloud Storage only for the new files you write. You will have to
>   update your app to handle this.

Now, some blob files has started to disapear from the storage, e.g:

http://lh5.ggpht.com/KVeondLUPgaRjE8wzN8iXg623vOIUHU1F2MLrqYR1KDjmGb1nFHV19QHF7wKfXmxqeqev32wX2zGv9I7qA

Interesting though is that the icon version of the image remain:

http://lh5.ggpht.com/KVeondLUPgaRjE8wzN8iXg623vOIUHU1F2MLrqYR1KDjmGb1nFHV19QHF7wKfXmxqeqev32wX2zGv9I7qA=s150-c

Note: I'm sure that it was not deleted by our code because our application never had code that delete images from the blob.

Any idea whats going on there and how to restore the missing images?

Comment: What are the app's error logs for the failing request? You should also show the code serving that request.

Comment: This is a static link that is managed by the appengine blobstore, there is no code serving the request. the API is abandon, so I couldn't use the code to delete it even if i try. this is an appengine issue.

Comment: OK, then the code producing/managing those URLs.

Comment: The code is abandon and deleted, any way I don't think it has anything to do with the code - the same method was used to upload all images - and now some are missing. the bug is in appengine - Dan, do u have specific info about this bug? do u have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Nope, my suspicion was about the code using a now deprecated method of accessing the blob data.